# "Bootstrap Modal Pop up" Youtube Video Autoplay, reopens the video when turned off

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I've added a youtube video to my website that starts automatically at boot-up on the home page. The video opens as bootstrap modal pop up. However, when pop up closes, the video starts playing again in the background.

First, I want the video to start automatically.

Second, the video is automatically stopped when "pop up" is turned off.

Third, don't let the pop-up video start playing again in the background.

Version * Bootstrap v3.0.3

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
  <!-- POPUP SCRIPT -->  
          <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
        $("#iframeYoutube").attr("src","#");
      })
    })   


    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myModal").modal("show");
      $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
      });
    });


    </script>




     <!-- HEADER -->
      <header id="header" class="main__header">   </header>

     <!-- POPUP BAŞLANGIÇ -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: #f9f9f900;">

        <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 0px;">

        <button type="button" class="close" style="padding:8px; background: white;" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <iframe id="iframeYoutube" width="100%" height="450px" alt="1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/example?&autoplay=1;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div> 
      <!-- POPUP BİTİŞ -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should trigger a function when pop-up is closed.This function should stop video to be played in the background.

```
$("#modal-close-button").click(function () {

  $("#video-stop-button").click(); 

  });


$("#video-stop-button").click(function () {

alert("The video should stop as the modal closes because a click on the close button will trigger the stop button ");

  });
```

You should call this function whenever your pop-up is closed to prevent video to be played in the background.

Comment: I've added the code you gave below my JS code. The problem still continues. There is another script on my site for the slider, could it be a problem from that script?

Comment: `code` <script type="text/javascript">
             
             $(function() {
  $('#carousel2').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
    var iframe = $(this).find('.item.active iframe');
    if(iframe.length > 0) {
      console.log('stop youtube video');
      iframe[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event": "command", "func":"stopVideo", "args": ""}', '*');
    }
     $('.item.active iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event": "command", "func":"pauseVideo", "args": ""}', '*')
  });
});
      </script> `code`

Comment: Do you call this function when modal is closed? I mean adding this code to Js but not calling it does not fix the problem